# Primeng multi select is not detecting changing value

Tags: angular6, primeng

*> >     >                 ***

> > ```
> > >     
> > >         1. my component :    
> > >                 onClose()
> > >                {  this.selectedWorkCenterData.forEach(data =>{
> > >     
> > >     >             this.selectedWorkCenterValue.push(data);
> > >     >           }) } 
> > >               on Row Select the data  
> > >     
> > >     ***
> > >     
> > >     > Blockquote
> > >     
> > >     ***on selection of rows from prime ng table to populate in multi select
> > >     
> > >     onRowSelect(event) {
> > >     >         this.selectedWorkCenterValue = [];
> > >     >         if (event.data["WORK_CENTER_ID"]) {
> > >     >           this.selectedWorkCenterData.push(event.data);
> > >     >           this.searchOnWorkCenters();
> > >     >         }
> >
> >
> >  my html: <p-multiSelect
> > >     >             [options]="selectedWorkCenterData"
> > >     >             maxSelectedLabels="10"
> > >     >             [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkCenterValue"
> > >     >             [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
> > >     >             optionLabel="{{ lookup_config }}"
> > >     >             defaultLabel="Choose Work Center"
> > >     >             (onChange)="choosenWorkCenters()"
> > >     >             #mySelect
> > ```
> >
> > Blockquote
>
> > ```
> > >
> > ```
> >
> > I had to do in my project:   on change of options from multi select , there is no updated values for dropdon . please help this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Try that (in every change push, delete e.g);

```
this.selectedWorkCenterValue = new Array<any>();
```

Comment: Iam making this.selectedWorkCenterValue = new Array<any>(); every time i push ,But for this.selectedWorkCenterData here iam pushing every row select of data from prime ng table (multi select of rows) this is updating this.selectedWorkCenterValue also. where as in multi select dropdown is not updating ith new values.